# ajax to run php file

Tags: php, ajax

I have this script in a .html file on my page and im trying to just run the getip.php file from here rather than to rename the file to .php.  I tried this ajax call but its not working and not logging the ip in the logfile.txt.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**Ajax in the head of the .html file:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "getip.php",

            }); // Ajax Call
        }); //event handler
   </script>
```

**Code from getip.php:**

```
<?php
// location of the text file that will log all the ip adresses
$file = 'logfile.txt';

// ip address of the visitor
$ipadress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// date of the visit that will be formated this way: 29/May/2011 12:20:03
$date = date('d/F/Y h:i:s');

// name of the page that was visited
$webpage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

// visitor's browser information
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// Opening the text file and writing the visitor's data
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');

fwrite($fp, $ipadress.' - ['.$date.'] '.$webpage.' '.$browser."\r\n");

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: response handler?.. `.done(function (data)) ?` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Also, you don't need a type, you could also do this: `$.ajax("getip.php").done(function() { alert("done"); }).fail(function(){ alert("failed"); });`

Comment: does the php file work when you access it directly? I would test that first, then once I was sure that was working, use Firebug (firefox extention) to look at what is being done with the ajax. You should also have a .done and .fail function on your ajax call so you can know what is happening

Comment: @Cookie_J5 The PHP file does work.

Comment: Can you get install Firebug and see what it's not working- firebug will tell you if it's at least calling the file and what parameters it's sending to you.. also if there are any errors such as 500 or 400 it will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$.post()` function instead? Example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.post('getip.php'); // Ajax Call
        }); //event handler
</script>
```

You can also add a callback as a second parameter.

Comment: tried your code again and this did in fact work.  I had left something in the ajax call that i wrote that was not working.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would use the full URL for the ajax call. Depending on your framework you might not be hitting the intended endpoint. You could try `echo 'test';` in your php file and adding a done handler to your ajax call to make sure you're hitting the php file in the first place:

```
.done(function( data ) {
  alert(data);
});
```